# Extend CSS build process in Meteor

Tags: css, meteor, meteor-plugin

I would like to post process my CSS files while Meteor builds my app. I saw that in 1.2 they introduced the Build Plugin option. When I try to register my plugin to deal with `.css` extensions, it gives me an error that there is already a plugin taking care of these files.

How can I add more steps to manipulate files on top of the current build process? I don't want to replace the current CSS concatenation and minification.

Thanks,
Tomer